# Check the user access to a Db in sql serverusing powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

How to check whether a user has access to a database in a SQL server using Powershell. I tried to execute a simple "select 1" command using that user. is there any better way of checking the access permissions for a user either windows authentication or SQL server auth?

Answer (score 0):

```
create login xyzloginX with password = 'xyzloginXP@ssw0rd'
go
exec
('
select HAS_DBACCESS(name) as hasdbaccess, name as dbname, SUSER_NAME() as loginname
from master.sys.databases
--where HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1
') as login = 'xyzloginX'
go

drop login xyzloginX
go
```